# Spring-MVC : Unable to access static files in the ressource folder

Tags: xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a maven webapp running in a tomcat server, using spring-mvc 4 dependency.and i can't load **login.css** file located in a folder named **css** inside the resource folder of the app. the request returns a 404 file not found error.

The URL being used to access the file is :
   http://localhost:8080/WFMConf/resources/css/login.css

the css doesn't load when i access the JSP page directly either.

here is the relevant code :

**Web.xml :**

```
<web-app>


<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring-database.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**servlet-context.xml :**

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/vues/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myApp.controllers" />


</beans:beans>
```

**spring-security.xml :**

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <!--  <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" /> -->
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/index" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" invalidate-session="true"/>
    <!--   enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/> 
</http>


<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
      users-by-username-query=
        "select login,pwd, enabled from utilisateur where login=?"
      authorities-by-username-query=
        "select login, role from role where login =?" />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**login.jsp :**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/login.css" />" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css" />
</head>
```

**Edit :**

the output link on the generated html is : 
`<link href="/WFMConf/resources/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">`

the directory structure is the following :

```
->src
  ->main
   ->java
      ->com.myapp.controllers.MainController
   ->resources
      ->JS
      ->img
      ->css
        ->login.css
   ->webapp
      ->WEB-INF
        ->spring
          ->appServlet
            ->servlet-context.xml
          ->spring-database.xml
          ->spring-security.xml
        ->vues
          ->login.jsp
        ->web.xml
```

Comment: can you post folder structure of your project.

Comment: How does that link look on the generated HTML?

Comment: i edited my question to include both the directory structure and the <link> on the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add below line in your `servlet-context.xml`.

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

And access the `css` from `login.jsp` like below.

```
<link href="<c:url value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/login.css" />" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css" />
```

Comment: this did not work. the page still returns a 404 as far as the login.css is concerned.